# Using order by round

Tags: linq

Here's the problem, I have inherited a database driven app written in asp.net...

At the moment it has the line

```
var ovs = (from i in data.ADS_TESTs orderby i.SampleNumber descending select i).Take(numToFetch);
```

I am very new to this, being a php, and sql background..

How would i write a round function into there, for example in sql i would write

```
ORDER BY ROUND(SampleNumber, 0) DESC, SampleNumber
```

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: Also, FYI, this has nothing at all to do with ASP.NET.

Comment: LINQ to what? LINQ to Objects, LINQ to SQL, LINQ to Entities? It really matter here.

Comment: Sorry guys, very new to this site, I was at the end of a 15 hour night shift and was probably not a  complete in my question as I should of been... I had tried lots of alternatives and it is the code behind a asp.net page. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Most query providers typically support the use common static methods.  Assuming LINQ to SQL, it supports the use of `Math.Round()`.

```
var ovs =
    (from i in data.ADS_TESTs
            // the overload of Round() supported needs the rounding mode
    orderby Math.Round(i.SampleNumber, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) descending,
            i.SampleNumber
    select i).Take(numToFetch);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can manipulate i.SampleNumber after orderby clause.
Yes as jeff told Math.Round() can be used.